# JsonDecode on Null at an URL

Tags: php, json, decode

I'm making a plugin that gets data from an external server through an encoded URL. To decode the output of the plugin I am using a JsonDecode, but it comes back 'NULL'everytime.

The code:

```
    $json = file_get_contents($goodurl);
    $data = json_decode($json);
    var_dump($data);
```

This is the response when requesting the URL:

```
{
  "schemaVersion": "1.0",
  "catalogueVersion": "4.0.5651.20898",
  "encoding": "UTF-8",
  "action": "info",
  "query": "catalogue",
  "success": "true",
  "response": {
    "title": "Presentations 2Go",
    "description": "Presentations2Go videoserver is an innovative solution to simply capture presentations and\/or lectures on video. The video image of the presenter is linked with the presentation and stored for later (re)use.",
    "logoUrl": "https:\/\/DEMO-FORMS.presentations2go.eu\/P2G\/images\/logo\/logo.png",
    "languages": [
      {"lang": "en"},
      {"lang": "nl"},
      {"lang": "de"},
      {"lang": "fr"},
      {"lang": "kr"},
      {"lang": "no"},
      {"lang": "pt"},
      {"lang": "dk"},
      {"lang": "cn"},
      {"lang": "ar"},
      {"lang": "se"},
      {"lang": "it"},
      {"lang": "es"},
      {"lang": "ru"},
      {"lang": "cy"},
      {"lang": "tw"}
    ],
    "videoCount": "380",
    "webmaster": "support@presentations2go.eu"
  }
}
```

And this is the output in JSON:

```
object(stdClass)#83 (7) { 

    ["schemaVersion"]=> string(3) "1.0" 

    ["catalogueVersion"]=> string(14) "4.0.5651.20898" 

    ["encoding"]=> string(5) "UTF-8" 

    ["action"]=> string(4) "info" 

    ["query"]=> string(9) "catalogue" 

    ["success"]=> string(4) "true" 

    ["response"]=> object(stdClass)#84 (6) { 

        ["title"]=> string(17) "Presentations 2Go" 

        ["description"]=> string(207) "Presentations2Go videoserver is an innovative solution to simply capture presentations and/or lectures on video. The video image of the presenter is linked with the presentation and stored for later (re)use." 

        ["logoUrl"]=> string(63) "https://DEMO-FORMS.presentations2go.eu/P2G/images/logo/logo.png" 

        ["languages"]=> array(16) { 

            [0]=> object(stdClass)#85 (1) { 

                    ["lang"]=> string(2) "en" 

                } 
                [1]=> object(stdClass)#86 (1) { 

                    ["lang"]=> string(2) "nl" 

                } 
                [2]=> object(stdClass)#87 (1) { 

                    ["lang"]=> string(2) "de" 

                } 
                [3]=> object(stdClass)#88 (1) {

                    ["lang"]=> string(2) "fr"

                } 
                [4]=> object(stdClass)#89 (1) {

                    ["lang"]=> string(2) "kr"

                } 
                [5]=> object(stdClass)#90 (1) {

                    ["lang"]=> string(2) "no"

                } 
                [6]=> object(stdClass)#91 (1) {

                    ["lang"]=> string(2) "pt"

                } 
                [7]=> object(stdClass)#92 (1) { 

                    ["lang"]=> string(2) "dk"

                } 
                [8]=> object(stdClass)#93 (1) {

                    ["lang"]=> string(2) "cn"

                } 
                [9]=> object(stdClass)#94 (1) { 

                    ["lang"]=> string(2) "ar"

                } 
                [10]=> object(stdClass)#95 (1) {

                    ["lang"]=> string(2) "se" 

                } 
                [11]=> object(stdClass)#96 (1) { 

                    ["lang"]=> string(2) "it" 

                } 
                [12]=> object(stdClass)#97 (1) { 

                    ["lang"]=> string(2) "es" 

                } 
                [13]=> object(stdClass)#98 (1) { 

                    ["lang"]=> string(2) "ru" 

                } 
                [14]=> object(stdClass)#99 (1) { 

                    ["lang"]=> string(2) "cy" 

                } 
                [15]=> object(stdClass)#100 (1) {

                    ["lang"]=> string(2) "tw" 

                } 
            } 

        ["videoCount"]=> string(3) "378" 

        ["webmaster"]=> string(27) "support@presentations2go.eu" 
    } 

}
```

I'm not that experienced JSON so I suspect there might be a syntax error in there. But I'm not sure what and how to solve it.

Comment: Well, it IS valid json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an object instead of an array.
Simply write:

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

To receive an associative array.

From the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: it indeed sets it to an array, but its still i te same format. Might this be because of the vardump?

Comment: Try using print_r($data) instead of var_dump($data)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
 $data = json_decode($json,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an object instead of an array.

To receive an associative array.

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

or you can access or get value of object like

```
echo $data->catalogueVersion;
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone already told you to set `json_decode` to true, when true returned objects will be converted into associative arrays., [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

I would suggest using the code below to view your array. Its is easier to read that way.

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
```